# MythTV gives an error when selecting "Watch TV"

Tags: 10.10, mythtv

I've set up MythTV for watching TV. I've configured the back end. I have a TV tuner, and a table of frequencies.

But when you start the front end and make the transition to the item "Watch TV", it shows a window with the message

> Error: MythTV is using all inputs, but there are no active recordings

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to post some backend logs (/var/log/mythtv/mythbackend.log). Likely this is due to you not going through steps 2,3, and 4 in mythtv-setup.